# Kill() function between two processes

Tags: c

Can I use the kill() function to send a signal to another process? It should be possible, but kill() fails and I can't understand why. 
I have two programs (process_1 and process_2). The first one should set a signal handler to increase a variable, than create a child that uses execve and loads process_2. The other program should send the signal using kill(). I used the shared memory to share process_1's pid through a struct (because I have other variables to share). The code of the first program is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define KEY_SM 1234
static int value_to_change=0;


typedef struct keys{
    pid_t pid_process;
}keynote;


static void test_handler(int signo){
    if(signo=SIGUSR1){
        printf("received SIGUSR1\n");
        value_to_change++;
    }
}


int main(){
    if((signal(SIGUSR1, test_handler))==SIG_ERR) perror("Errore allocazione SIGUSR1");
    int flags = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|IPC_CREAT;
    size_t shm_size = sizeof(keynote);
    int shm_id = shmget(KEY_MC, shm_size, flags);
    keynote *chv = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    chv->pid_process=getpid();
    printf("%d\n",chv->pid_process);


    int process_2;
    process_2=fork();
    if(process_2==0){
        char* argv[]={"process_1", "process_2", NULL};
        if((execve("process_2", argv, NULL))<0) perror("execve error");
    exit(0);
    }else if(process_2<0)perror("fork error");

    return 0;
}
```

The second program code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

 #define KEY_SM 1234

    typedef struct keys{
        pid_t pid_process;
    }keynote;


static void signal_to_send(pid_t process){
    int ret=kill(process, SIGUSR1);
    printf("%d", ret);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid_of_process_1;
    int flags = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|IPC_CREAT;
    size_t shm_size = sizeof(keynote);

    int shm_id = shmget(KEY_MC, shm_size, flags);  
    keynote *chv = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    signal_to_send(chv->pid_process);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. "I'm having some truble" is neither a question nor even a good description of what your specific problem is. Please review: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `process_1` does not wait for `process_2`. It just exits immediately. At which point `process_2` may not even have started. So when `process_2` sends the signal, `process_1` is likely to not exist anymore.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it. Thank you

Comment: `if(signo=SIGUSR1){` -->> `if(signo == SIGUSR1){` Plus: you should not use printf() in a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

`process_1` does not wait for `process_2`. It just exits immediately. At which point `process_2` may not even have started. So when `process_2` sends the signal, `process_1` is likely to not exist anymore.
                    – kaylum